# Solve the provided questions below using FASM

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, hex, fasm

So this is the question:

> Using the flat assembler (FASM), write a program that converts an 8-bit integer to binary and hexadecimal using bitwise operators.  Do not use external functions. You may use the algorithm below.
>
> Ask user to enter a number 0 - 255 and store into Num
>
> Algorithm to convert Value to binary:
>
> 1. Set Count to 0. Move Num into a variable named Temp
> 2. Move Temp into EAX then AND EAX with 128 (binary 10000000)
> 3. if result is zero, output "0"
> 4. if result is not zero, output "1"
> 5. shift Temp left one digit
> 6. increment Count
> 7. if Count < 8, jump to step (2)
>
> Algorithm to convert Value to hexadecimal:
>
> 1. Move Num into a variable named Temp
> 2. shift Temp right 4 digits to isolate left 4 digits
> 3. if Temp <=9, print Temp
> 4. if Temp >=10, add 55 to Temp and print the ASCII character
> 5. Move Num into a variable named Temp
> 6. AND Temp with 15 (binary 00001111) to isolate right 4 digits
> 7. if Temp <=9, print Value
> 8. if Temp >=10, add 55 to Temp and print the ASCII character

Example output:

```
This x86 assembly program converts an integer to binary and hex.

Enter an integer from 0 - 255: 73
Binary: 01001001
Hex:    49
```

This is how I attempted it:

```
format PE console
include 'win32ax.inc'
section '.code' code readable executable
start:
                cinvoke printf, "Enter an integer from 0-255:"
                cinvoke scanf, "%d", Num
                call BinStep1
                call HexStep1
                cinvoke printf, "%c%c", 10,10
                jmp start

BinStep1:
        cinvoke printf, "%cBin:",10
        mov [Count],0
        mov eax, [Num]
        mov [Temp], eax

BinStep2:
        mov eax, [Temp]
        and eax, 128 ; result is either 0 or 128

BinStep3:
        jnz BinStep4
        ;output a zero
        jmp BinStep5

BinStep4:
        ;output a one

BinStep5:
        ;shift temp left one digit

BinStep6:
        ;increment Count

BinStep7:
        cmp[Count], 8
        jl BinStep2
        ret

HexStep1:
        cinvoke printf, "%cHex: ",10
        mov eax, [Num]
        mov [Temp], eax

HexStep2:
        shr [Temp], 4
        call PrintHexDigit

HexStep5:
        mov eax, [Num]
        mov [Temp], eax

HexStep6:
        ;And Temp with 15 to isolate right 4 bits
        call PrintHexDigit
        ret

PrintHexDigit:
             cmp [Temp],9
             jp GreaterThan9
             cinvoke printf, "%d", [Temp]
             ret

GreaterThan9: ;print A-F
              add [Temp], 55
              cinvoke printf, "%c",[Temp]
              ret



section '.data' data readable writeable

Num   dd  0
Temp  dd  0
Count dd  0


section '.idata' import data readable

library msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll',kerne132,'kerne132.dll'
import msvcrt, printf,'printf',scanf,'scanf'
```

But my results did not came out as expected. This is how the output came out:

[output after I run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhnhk.png)

Can anyone help me out in fixing this program?

Answer (score 1):

### BinStep

> ```
>    ;output a zero
>
>    ;output a one
>
>    ;shift temp left one digit
>
>    ;increment Count
> ```

> But my results did not came out as expected.

I wonder, did you expect something to come out when you didn't even replace the comments by actual instructions?
And anyway, the *BinStep* loop is really an **infinite loop**, because not incrementing *Count* will bring about that `cmp [Count], 8` `jl BinStep2` will always be true and therefore forever jumping to the top of the loop!

```
BinStep1:
        cinvoke printf, "%cBinary:",10
        mov [Count],0
        mov eax, [Num]
        mov [Temp], eax

BinStep2:
        mov eax, [Temp]
        and eax, 128           ; result is either 0 or 128

BinStep3:
        jnz BinStep4
        cinvoke printf "0"     ;output a zero
        jmp BinStep5

BinStep4:
        cinvoke printf "1"     ;output a one

BinStep5:
        shl [Temp], 1          ;shift temp left one digit

BinStep6:
        inc [Count]            ;increment Count

BinStep7:
        cmp [Count], 8
        jl  BinStep2
        ret
```

### HexStep

> ```
>    ;And Temp with 15 to isolate right 4 bits
> ```

Again I see a comment that didn't get translated to assembly. Just as easy as the `shr [Temp], 4` that you knew about, this needs to become `and [Temp], 15`.
The *PrintHexDigit* subroutine has a typo. The `jp GreaterThan9` instruction is testing the parity flag. What you need is `jg GreaterThan9`

```
HexStep1:
        cinvoke printf, "%cHex:   ",10
        mov  eax, [Num]
        mov  [Temp], eax

HexStep2:
        shr  [Temp], 4
        call PrintHexDigit

HexStep5:
        mov  eax, [Num]
        mov  [Temp], eax

HexStep6:
        and  [Temp], 15        ;And Temp with 15 to isolate right 4 bits
        call PrintHexDigit     <<< Tail-call
        ret

PrintHexDigit:
        cmp  [Temp], 9
        jg   GreaterThan9
        cinvoke printf, "%d", [Temp]
        ret

GreaterThan9: ;print A-F
        add  [Temp], 55
        cinvoke printf, "%c", [Temp]
        ret
```

I fully understand that you want to follow the provided algorithms to the letter, but you could remove that tail-call from the *HexStep* and still comply:

```
HexStep1:
        cinvoke printf, "%cHex:   ",10
        mov  eax, [Num]
        mov  [Temp], eax
        shr  [Temp], 4
        call .Hex
        mov  eax, [Num]
        mov  [Temp], eax
        and  [Temp], 15
.Hex:   cmp  [Temp], 9
        jg   .GT9
        cinvoke printf, "%d", [Temp]
        ret
.GT9:   add  [Temp], 55
        cinvoke printf, "%c", [Temp]
        ret
```